# Append a java file with headlines

Tags: java

Thanks to this community, I have read many tutorials on different method on how to write information into a txt file in java. but what if I want this file to be formatted and write information under each section of the file ?

Exemple of what I'm trying to do in myfile.txt  is :

```
                    list of Apartments
                 ========================

Region===============Country==========Adresse =======PriceMunicipality 
writeRegionHere  writeCountryHere   writeAdressHere  writeMunicipalityHere
```

And every time I add a new apartment, the info must be added at the end witch is an easy step for me , I'm just have no idea how to write them using this format

Much Appreciation

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Paste your code into your question for others to examine :)

Comment: The functionality you are looking for is really more like a database, if you want a nice solution for this problem i highly suggest using one.

Comment: Have you tried a `Formatter`? Even a simple `printf()` could probably do what you want. https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs160/.Spring16/resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf

Comment: @Ldvg of course DB is the best solution but the task I'm asked for denies it .

Comment: @EugenHotaj Thanks ! I will take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to format the text

```
    private static void printRow(String c0, String c1, String c2, String c3 ) {
    System.out.printf("%-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s%n", c0, c1, c2, c3);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

        printRow(" ", "", "List of Appartments", " ");
        printRow( "==============", "==============", "==============", "==============");

        printRow("Region", "Country", "Adresse", "PriceMunicipilaty");
        printRow("==============", "==============", "==============", "==============");
        printRow("Adress1", "Adress1" , "Adress1", "Adress2");
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will try this

Answer (score 1):

if you are outputting in a .txt file the .txt file itself does not support any real formatting such as Bold, underline etc unlike .doc, .odt. so to format a text you have to hardcore it the way the output should look normally. You can use '\t', '\n' and many more special character to display the output as desired, just as @Drogian has written.